# Correcting colors for logos on Business cards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-conversion, print-production, corel-draw, overprint

I am designing business cards in Illustrator, however my printers use Corel Draw and some of the logos do not show up on their side. They mention 'overprinting', but I do not know what that means.

They also say that the cards have a combination of RGB, CMYK and Pantone, how do I change all the colors to CMYK?

[image: Illustrator screen shot]

From the printer.....

[image: Screen shot from the printers]

Answer (score 4):

Note that your logos are  not "disappearing" in Corel.

The printer is showing you a screenshot of elements that have incorrect coloring - RGB and Spot colors. What you see in their screenshot is what needs fixing.

[image: Wrong colors]

To correct these you need to select them and change the fill/stroke to correct CMYK colors.

By **Overprint**, the printer is referring to setting black elements to overprint. This ensures they aren't screened and print solid on top of other colors. It is customary to want small black elements to overprint for optimum appearance. Overprint *never* means "bleed' when talking to a print provider. It means Overprint.

To do this you select anything with a black fill or stroke and then tick the `Overprint` options on the **Attributes Panel** (Window > Attributes).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your printer isnt being very helpful by the sound of it, I thought professional Corel use dissolved 10 years ago along with Quark...!!

You should be sending them your files as a PDF (they should also supply a spec) not a native format. Along with a .JPG proof for them to check.

You must use ONLY CMYK elements within your print design in AI or when you save out to PDF the RGB elements will be converted to CMYK and the colours will change slightly, sometimes dramatically - not always a big issue, but can cause issues.

To convert: select all the objects in the document. Next goto Edit -> Edit Colors, and select the "Convert to CMYK"

Comment: Thanks DL I attached screen shots and what they call Overprint(?) - part of the logos disappearing on their side. not referring to bleed

Comment: @GosiaMiller - It doesn't look like bits are disappearing, it looks like they have disabled all CMYK elements to show you which ones need converting.

Comment: 'Overprint' is **not** the same as bleed. Overprint is the setting to have multiple inks overlap each other to prevent white gaps when the plates are (slightly) misaligned. In this case, the cyan and black in the 'Avenue' logo.

Comment: Right ok understood, its not something I've encountered before but makes sense yes.

Comment: Overprint is the opposite of knockout. Printing objects on top of underlying objects instead of knocking out a white hole in underlaying objects. I've answered a question about this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84114/84899. It's focusing on InDesign, but it's the same principle in Illustrator.