# Printing stacked layers on transparent sheet maintaining each layers integrity

Tags: print-design, layers

I would like to be able to print stacked layers on my HP laser 452dw transparent paper maintaining the integrity of each layer, I put a text of my question on the images I uploaded.

[image: Print Side]

[image]

Comment: hi, your question is kinda confusing. What exactly is the end result you're looking for? Also please do not add text in the images, it's terrible for legibility. Write it as regular text.

Comment: I would like to be able to print full layer of cyan and full layer of magenta on top of it but single pass so the intersection of the two will show one layer on top of the other one. simply here is the setting:

Comment: I am using ghost white toner on my hp 452 laser printer and I want to print the colors first and the white on top of them without swapping toners and without two passes., so what I did I mapped CMYK to CMY that way every black information in the image is going now to mix from CMY, and I kept the white toner in the printer and in the empty black channel after the mapping I put the inverse of black which is now going to be white and I printed single pass.

Comment: when I did this I ended up white overwhelming the under colors instead of printing on top of them, I need to find a way of keeping the under color layer intact. in my example I showed my problem wherever the white goes on top of the color IT KNOCKS IT OUT ISTEAD OF LAYING ON TOP OF IT.

Comment: I do not believe what you are trying to do is possible. *Especially* as a single pass. Print technology simply does *not* use "layers". Print technologies flatten artwork. As far as I'm aware *all* print technologies flatten. Unless you have some innovative printer, you won't get where you want to go in my opinion. It *must* be a two pass print at a minimum. (I had to watch the video link below to even understand the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with your specific problem, but normally overprinting can be achieved by placing the object on top and choosing the blend mode *multiply*.

In InDesign/Illustrator (you don't say which program you are using), you can also/instead try to check the object's *Attributes > Overprint Fill*.

In InDesign, the special swatch *Black*, can be set to always overprint at 100% in *Edit > Preferences > Appearance of Black*.

It could be a problem that many printers do not accept CMYK values and will internally convert them to RGB before converting them back to its own (secret) CMYK values so you might not be able to gain full control of the percentages of the inks. Your print looks clean though. Are the inks 100% pure?

If any of this helps, it could be fun to see the result. Is the white ink really opaque enough to cover the other inks?

(The answer i wrote [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/84114/84899) is somewhat related.)

Comment: It is a laser printer with individual CMYK toners HP 452dw. So yes the colors are 100% clear because I chose spot colors

Comment: When I lay them and multiply still whatever on top takes out the overlap from the bottom and shows through and does not simply overlay it on top

Comment: So far two passes is the only way to achieve what I want, I am looking for a one pass solution

Comment: I posted videos to describe what I want to do and what stone wall I hit:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5OQ9Atir1c&t=1s

Comment: I had a quick look at your videos (no sound) and I have a better understanding of your setup. It's probably too printer specific for me to be able to help. But it could be something trivial. Does the channels look OK before printing (no knockout)? Are you using an ordinary black channel and mapping to white when printing or are you mapping to a white spot color before printing? Maybe you could do it the other way around. Maybe the "Solidity" setting of each channel matters?